# How do I determine the calling procedure from within a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, scheduled-tasks

From time to time, when you install freeware, you are presented with the option to install trial versions of programs that you do not want.  If you are careless and anxious to get the freeware installed, you will click "OK" to the panels of an install process without paying attention to what you are agreeing to.

Soulless suits in glass towers somewhere will call some programs "aggressive marketing applications" that other people will call ad-ware or even viruses.  Some of these programs redirect web browsers home page or even try to disguise themselves as search engines.  They bore deep into your operating system and some are clever enough to reinstall themselves after an annoyed user finds and deletes them.

The frustrated user can find himself in mess where hidden and disguised applications are difficult to track down. System level tasks launched at different times and by different events further cloaks the user's ability to track down and remove the malware.

After several attempts to clean my computer, I am still plagued with a pop up lessage that says a DLL, CATHEL~1.DLL is being accessed that it not there.

[image]

All I know is that a scheduled task is trying to launch a DLL that no longer exists.  We tried to stop this annoyance by:

1. trying to pinpoint the task that was causing this problem and removing it or stopping it.
2. trying to run ad-ware removal software.

Both these methods failed.

Next, I tried something a bit more sneaky.  The message I have presented here was origionally different.  The error message origionally said that it could not find the DLL at all.  So what I did was simply create a DLL in visual studio and placed it where the "RunDll" was looking for it.  But then, since the stored procedure or the task was trying to call a method in the DLL, there was a new error message that peiordically pops up:[image]

So my question is this.  How can I code the DLL such that it can determine the name of the calling application?  I have written a very simple and empty DLL in Visual Studio 2008 C++ that produces the "CATHEL~1.DLL" and I put the release version of the DLL where the system expects to find it.  How do I create the "Start" method, and how would I modify it to output the name of the task or procedure that is calling it?

Comment: I suggest you get `AutoRuns` from MSDN TechNet and use that to look for whatever that does the starting. You can get the name of the process that loads the DLL, and all of its parents. But most likely it's some system process that gets tricked into loading the DLL by some autorun method. Actually that DLL load may be invoked by yet another malware DLL.

Comment: This is not the answer you are seeking, but have you tried using SysInternals Process Explorer or Process Monitor to investigate this? They've got everything you need to get to the bottom of this type of thing.

Comment: I will try your suggestion, datenwolf and Gunter, before giving the more progam-oriented suggestion below.  Autoruns looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple (given you know how to query a process' parent): Give the DLL a `DllMain`. To query the process parent we need a small helper function (can be found by Googling "windows get process parent"). We modify it a bit to query based on process handle and to return a handle instead of an ID

```
HANDLE GetParentProcessHandle(HANDLE hParent) // Modified from Napalm @ NetCore2K
{
 ULONG_PTR pbi[6];
 ULONG ulSize = 0;
 LONG (WINAPI *NtQueryInformationProcess)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, ULONG ProcessInformationClass,
  PVOID ProcessInformation, ULONG ProcessInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength); 
 *(FARPROC *)&NtQueryInformationProcess = 
  GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("NTDLL.DLL"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");
 if(NtQueryInformationProcess){
  if(NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 0,
    &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &ulSize) >= 0 && ulSize == sizeof(pbi))
     return OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pbi[5]);
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

We can now use this to query the chain of calling processes and emit their image names:

```
char exename[512];
DWORD len = 512;
HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
do {
    memset(exename, 0, len);
    QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, exename, &len);
    MessageBox(NULL, exename, "EXE name", MB_OK);
    hProcess = GetParentProcessHandle(hProcess);
} while(hProcess);
```

Note that I did not test the above code; this is just to give you the idea.